# JQGrid - disable checkbox based on value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I would like to disable a checkbox in JQGrid where `multiselect: true` is set.

It was touched on here:

[Disabling checkbox in “multiselect:true” mode for a specific row in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356990/disabling-checkbox-in-multiselecttrue-mode-for-a-specific-row-in-jqgrid)

but I'm not sure how to implement this solution since I am new to jqgrid.

I'm looking to do something like:

```
if (amount > 50) {
disable checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 1):

best way is to write custom formatter : http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

```
function checkBoxFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   if (rowObject. amount > 50) { 
    //return disabled checkbox string
    }else{
    //return  enabled checkbox string
    }
   return new_format_value
}
```

and when constructing jqgrid :

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'checkbox', index:'checkbox', width:60, align:"center", formatter:checkBoxFormatter},
      ...
   ]
...
})
```