# jQgrid: multiselect true - make each row checked by default on page load

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    url:call_url,
        datatype: "json",
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20,30,40],
    colNames:[<?php echo $col;?>],
    colModel:[
                {name:'USER_ID',index:'USER_ID', align:'center',search:false,hidden:true,key:true},
        {name:'PROJECT_NAME',index:'PROJECT_NAME', align:'center',search:false,hidden: true},
        {name:'EMP_NAME',index:'EMP_NAME', sortable:true,summaryType:'count',summaryTpl : 'Total ({0}) Resource Hours' },
        <?php for($i=1;$i<=count($cal_arr);$i++) {?>
        {name:'<?php echo $i;?>',index:'<?php echo $i;?>',search:false,align:"center",sortable:false ,width:80 },
        <?php } ?>
    ],
    pager: "#page",
        multiselect: true,
    shrinkToFit :true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    grouping: true, 
    groupingView : { groupField : ['PROJECT_NAME'], 
                    groupColumnShow : [false], 
                    groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
                    groupCollapse : false, 
                    groupOrder: ['asc'], 
                    groupSummary : [true], 
                    showSummaryOnHide: true,
                    groupDataSorted : true },
    sortname: 'EMP_NAME',
    caption: "Programatically block selection of some grid row',
    gridComplete: function () {
                    var recs = $("#grid").getGridParam("records");
                    $( ".mycontent" ).remove();
                    if (recs == 0 || recs == null) {
                        $('#grid').after("<div class='mycontent' style='color:red;text-align:center'>No Record Found</div>");
                        $("#btn_submit").hide();
                    }
            },


        loadComplete: function () {
            $("#cb_grid").click(); 
        },

            rowattr: function (item) {
                    if (parseInt(item.ID) == 1) {
                        return {"class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"};
                    }
            },

            //prevent selection of disabled rows
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                if ($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").hasClass("ui-state-disabled")) {
                    return false;   // not allow select the row
                }
                return true;    // allow select the row
            }

})
```

Above code does this

[image: Does this]

Required is

[image: This is required]

Using jqGrid with `multiselect:true` how to set each row checked by default on page load ? jQgrid Version - 4.6

Comment: Please include *always* which jqGrid fork and which version of jqGrid you use. Different versions have different possibilities. If you use still jqGrid 4.6 for example, then you can load all data selected if `datatype: "local"`, `deselectAfterSort: false`, `multiselect: true` and `selarrrow` array are filled with ids of rows which need be selected during loading.

Comment: @Oleg, in my case its `datatype: "json",` and `multiselect: true`. How can I fetch ids of rows and keep it selected by default on page load for the first time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jqGrid 4.6 with `datatype: "json"` and no `loadonce: true` option then you have not so much possibilities. You have to enumerate all multiselect checkboxes of the grid and select there. So you can do

```
$("#cb_grid").click(); // "grid" is the grid id
```

inside of `loadComplete` callback for example. If you would think about all cases you will probably add more additional criteria, because `loadComplete` will be called on sorting, paging and so on.

**UPDATED:** You code have `$('.cbox').attr('checked', true);` line inside of `rowattr`. In the way you don't change the checkbox of the row, which is not yet exist. Instead of that you set `checked` attribute with **wrong value `true` instead of `"checked"` on the checkbox of the column header**. You should remove the line to be able to use the code which I suggested you:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $("#cb_" + this.id).click();
},
rowattr: function (item, rd, rowid) {
    //$('.cbox').attr('checked', true);
    if (parseInt(rowid) === 10) {
        return {"class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"};
    }
},
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").hasClass("ui-state-disabled")) {
        return false;   // not allow select the row
    }
    return true;    // allow select the row
}
```

see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aagxejj5/4/

Comment: Oleg: I replaced my code with your fiddle code and still it does not select all the checkbox of the row but only `cb_grid`. The code responsible to keep all rows selected is `loadComplete: function () {
        $("#cb_" + this.id).click();
    }` but unfortunately its not working for me

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: I posted you the demo which works. So the problem which you describes is **not some common jqGrid proble, but the problem in your specific code**. You can modify the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aagxejj5/1/ so that it reproduces the problem, save it and post me the URL. Only having the demo which not work I can help you.

Comment: Pls find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aagxejj5/25/. I have added my complete code with your fiddle. Specifc code is followed by `loadComplete`.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: You demo don't display anything because of syntax error. After replacing `"<?php echo SITE_URL."someValidUrl"?>"` to `new_call_url ="<?php echo SITE_URL.'someValidUrl'?>";` to `new_call_url ="someValidUrl"` it works like expected without any problem: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aagxejj5/26/

Comment: Your code seems correct but I can not figure out the issue why its not working for me. I am really bothering you from last few hours. appreciate your genuine help. accepting your answer.

Comment: You are welcome! Such problems are really easy to debug, but one need to have the demo. Do you verified that `loadComplete` callback will be called? (you can just insert `alert("OK");` inside). The code which you posted contains some syntax errors: `caption: "Programatically block selection of some grid row',` instead of `caption: "Programatically block selection of some grid row",` (wrong closing quote). If you have the same in your real code then it could be the reason that some options/callbacks not works.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: Another common remark. I see that you used voting only 62 times in 2 years, 3 months. Do you seen so seldom helpful information on stackoverflow? *You have right to vote 30 questions or answers* **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). Stackoverflow and google use the voting counter as the main criteria for ordering of search results. Only if real developers found some answer helpful then it will be easy found. So **if you want help other people to find helpful information of stackoverflow you should more use your voting right**.

Comment: Oleg: Checked and `loadComplete` is being called. Also real code does not have any syntax errors as I rectified. Could be some other issue which I need to figure out. Yes I ll use my voting rights generously now

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: Do you verified that the rows will selected if you click on `"#cb_grid"` (checkbox of top of multiselect column) manually? Which web browser you use for debugging? You can for example set breakpoint inside of `loadComplete` and verify thet `$("#cb_" + this.id).length` is 1. Which version of jQuery you use? If it is not so old the you can add in Watch window `$._data($("#cb_" + this.id)[0], "events")` to see that `click` is bound to the event. You can post new comment after you verified all that.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: You should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and set the breakpoint on [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2530) and to go some steps over to see that [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2552) will be executed for every line of your grid.

Comment: Oleg: verfied `$("#cb_" + this.id).length` and its `1`. Also rows will be selected if I click on `#cb_grid` ((checkbox of top of multiselect column)). I can make it work with `loadComplete: function () {
                $("#cb_" + this.id).click(); //enable checkbox on top of multiselect column
                $('input.cbox').prop('checked',true); //enable other checkboxes
                $("tr.jqgrow").addClass('ui-state-highlight'); //highlight row
            }`

Comment: I have to click twice to uncheck other check boxes.