# Skip checkbox in multi select in jqgrid conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I saw [Oleg answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259262/jqgrid-multiselect-and-disable-check-conditional) when clicking the multiselect checkbox in the jqgrid header it remove the check when the checkbox is disabled. `(correct me if i'm wrong)`. But in my case I want to skip the rowdata or I don't want to check the checkbox if the row value `Status is approved`.

[image]

I tried this one

```
onSelectAll: function (aRowids, status) {
  $.each(aRowids, function (i, val) {
     var gridId = "#List";
     var rowData = jQuery(gridId).jqGrid('getRowData', val);
     var g = $("#List");
     var cbs = $("tr.jqgrow > td > " + rowData.Status == "Approved", g[0]);
     cbs.removeAttr("checked");
   }
}
```

but nothing happen. It still checks the status approved.

Comment: Can you show the generated html ?

Comment: @pirs okay wait i'll make a screenshot. DOne

Comment: no lol ... the `<html>` code with tags please.. ;-)
One row would be enough.

Comment: @pirs do you mean my html view code?. for my jqgrid?.

Comment: The code generated in your console, to see the tags arguments of your jqGrid rows.. i could have it to know the selector.

Comment: @pirs sorry I am new to web programming. Can you give me an example screenshot so I will know what will i show you.

Comment: In your page, Right click on a jqGrid row > Show code inspector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157330/discussion-between-kira-and-pirs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/HJema/632/

```js
var myData = [{
    id: 1,
    status: "Rejected"
}, {
    id: 2,
    status: "Approved"
}, {
    id: 3,
    status: "Rejected"
}, ];

$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["Id", "Status"],
    colModel: [{
        name: "id",
        index: "id",
        sorttype: "int"
    }, {
        name: "status",
        index: "status"
    }],
    caption: "Viz Test",
    pager: '#pager',
    search: true,
    multiselect: true,
    data: myData,
    loadComplete: function(data) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
       if(data.rows[i].status == "Approved"){   
         $('#jqg_list_' + (i+1)).attr('disabled', true);
        }
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

> There is some problem with the Stackoverflow snippet, please refer to the jsfiddle.

Hope this will help you

Comment: results undefined.

Comment: @KiRa Look precisely the code because it is correct, you could use it as well

Comment: Thanks. I just modify the code a bit because the id is not base on the length of the jqgrid and the `.status` is undefined that I use this `for (var i = 0; i < e.rows.length; i++) {
                if (e.rows[i].cell[13] == "Approved") {
                    $('#jqg_DTRCorrectedApprovalList_' + e.rows[i].cell[1]).attr('disabled', true);
                }
            }`

Comment: One final question. It is possible to remove the highlight if the status is approved?.

Comment: @KiRa Yes you can remove the highlight