# Enable or Disable selection of a Check Box in jqgrid depending on some specific column value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a jqgrid, where I want to select the rows which has value "Running" in Agent Status Column. For rest of the status, I should not be able to select the row.

The JQGrid code

```
 datatype: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    colNames: ['Id', 'Machine Name', 'IP Address', 'Discovered Date', 'Agent Install Status', 'Agent Installation Date', 'Agent Status', 'Agent Version', 'Last HeartBeat Recieved'],
    colModel: [            
        { name: 'id', hidden: false, width: 15, key: true },
        { name: 'machineName', width: 120 },
        { name: 'ipAddress', width: 60 },
        { name: 'discoveredDate', width: 110, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'y-m-d', newformat: 'l, F d, Y' } },
        { name: 'agentInstallStatus', width: 70 },
        { name: 'agentInstallationDate', width: 110, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'y-m-d', newformat: 'l, F d, Y' } },
        { name: 'agentStatusName', width: 90 , edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"Running"} },
        { name: 'agentVersion', width:50},
        { name: 'lastHeartBeatRecieved', width: 110, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'y-m-d', newformat: 'l, F d, Y' } }
    ],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,      
    width: gwdth,
    height: 650,
    rowNum: 10,        
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    mtype: 'GET',
    multiselect: true,
    multipleSearch: true,
    pager: "#jqGridPager"
});
```

[image]

Is it possible that I show checkBoxes only for the Running Status?

I am completely new to this environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two main options to implement your requiremens:

- use `rowattr` callback to *disable* the rows based on the content of `"agentStatusName"` column. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/disableRows.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33628065/315935).
- use `beforeSelectRow` callback (and `onSelectAll` too) to prevent selection of rows based on the content of `"agentStatusName"` column.

The first choice is the mostly simple and safe. The second one is more flexible. One can allow to edit rows (if it is required), but still prevent selection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. It worked for me, I just needed to add rowattr callback for the second link provided by you.

Comment: is it possible that I can disable only the Check Box column instead of the entire row? If yes, Could you please share a demo link

Comment: @AbhishekPandey: 1) The current code of free jqGrid from GitHub support [hasMultiselectCheckBox](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2022-L2023) callback which can be used to **remove** the checkboxes from some rows (based on the content). 2) if you don't want to remove checkbox, but to disable only, you can use `cellattr` in `cb` column (callback can be set in `onInitGrid`). `cellattr` can set the same classes like `rowattr`.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey: The disadvantage of above two implementations: one have to add `beforeSelectRow` and `onSelectAll` to prevent selection (like in [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5260847/315935)). Thus the way with disabling the row is the preferred way.

Comment: oleg : Ok, Thanks for the help and reply