# jQgrid: Disable checkbox click and select checkbox only when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid using multiselect option. There are two different functionality that I have to implement.

**Functionality 1:** 
    I have to disable check checkbox depends upon some condition. For that I am using below block of code in beforrowselect event.

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
    if( $("#jqg_TableId_"+rowid).attr("disabled") ){
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

The functionality is working fine with this block of code.

**Functionality 2:** But issue is when I click on anywhere in the row, the checkbox get selected but the checkbox value is not coming out correct. The value of checkbox is accurate when I click inside the area of checkbox. For that I want to restrict the user to click exactly on checkbox area to get checkbox clicked. For that I am using below mentioned block of code.

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) { 
   return $(e.target).is('input[type=checkbox]');
},
```

If I am using any one block alone then its working fine for that functionality.
I need to implement both the functionality but both the block returning value. It is not possible to return value for both the condition. Please help me out How can I implement both the functionality.

Below is the complete code that I have to implement.

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) { 
    if( $("#jqg_TableId_"+rowid).attr("disabled") ){
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
 return $(e.target).is('input[type=checkbox]');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to include in every question which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use. I suppose that the problem which you describe exist because you use some old version of jqGrid.

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4ga1ekh3/3/ uses free jqGrid 4.12.1 (it's the fork of jqGrid which I develop more as one year) and the following code

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
    if (item.closed) {
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

to deny selection of rows which have `closed: true` property. The click on any place on the row works in the same way like clicking on the checkbox.

I sill would recommend you to consider to use another way, which I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629176/315935). It sets just

```
rowattr: function (rd) {
    if (rd.closed) {
        return {
            "class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"
        };
    }
}
```

See another demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4ga1ekh3/4/. It set disabled class on "closed" rows, which prevent selection of the row in case clicking on the column header of select column (Select All functionality).

Comment: The block in beforeSelectRow for disabling checkbox select is working as expected but the rowattr event is not working as per requirement. The entire row is disable while returning"class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents". The checkbox need be be checked only while clicking on over the checkbox area.

Comment: @user2992704: Yes, it's what is expected for me. Setting of rows disables makes two things at once: shows the user which rows can't be selected 2) fix the problem with selection of all rows. One can us some other predefined classes instead: `ui-subgrid`, `jqgroup` or `jqfoot`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4ga1ekh3/5/- One have to combine **both** `rowattr` and `beforeSelectRow`.